# OData Related Field Select Syntax

Tags: sql, wcf, odata

Just wondering what the proper syntax is to add a related field to a select statement. Example Employees all have a department which is set in the departmentID field in the Employee table. What is the OData select syntax if i want to pull back all employees but only want to show their FirstName and DepartmentName. I was thinking it would be something like http://example.com/odata.svc/Employees?$select=FirstName,+Department.DepartmentName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for that is: `http://mywebsite.com/odata.svc/Employees?$select=FirstName,Department/DepartmentName&$expand=Department`

A related (working) example from Stack Overflow's OData API would be:
[http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Users?$select=DisplayName,Badges/Name&$expand=Badges](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Users?%24select=DisplayName,Badges/Name&%24expand=Badges)